# How to Connect Android App with a Local Web Sever using wifi

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-studio

**Android app Connectivity with Local Web Server**
I want to connect my android app with local web server to access my php files and store data into web server database.

I also tried to use free hosting web site [000webhost.com](http://000webhost.com) but their database didn't provide me InnoDB DB engine, They have MYISAM which doesn't provide foreign key property...
please suggest me any solution for this issue...??

Comment: I have done all XAMPP Server configurations with http-config files and able to access my server through MY IP address but not able to access through my android device browser....

Comment: I want to store my data in my local server database through my android device where my app is installed...

Is it possible to save data through android device over wifi....??

Answer (score 0):

1、you can connect to you local web server through 127.0.0.1/yourproject/path

2、check you ip, like 192.168.0.110 etc.

3、try to access 192.168.0.110/youproject/path in your phone browser.

if you can access in you browser, that's your testing address

Comment: what emulator you use.?
web server you think... is on diferent machine?

Comment: can you reach your webserver from your phone..?
use yourd cell phone browser..
how is the result..?

Comment: i am using virtual machine for my webserver, my phone connect to same router as my virtual machine, and have same segment ip so my server and my phone can communicate well, please ensure like you can reach your web server..

Comment: No, I am not reaching to my web server through my cell phone...@ntaloventi

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
is your manifest have this..?

Answer (score 0):

If using windows get your server ip by running:

```
ipconfig
```

in the Command Prompt. Then search for IPv4 that is your server ip;

If Using Linux Use:

```
ifconfig
```

in terminal. Then get inet addr field in wlan0.

Now you have ip address of server. 
Use it as: http://yourserveripadress